# Finding Area between curves

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, definite-integrals

Find the area enclosed between the circles:

$x^2 + (y- 3.5)^2 = (3.5)^2$
and
$(x-3.5)^2 + y^2 = (3.5)^2$

I tried using definite Integrals but I was unable to frame the equation. Please help me

Comment: @imranfat thanks for the edit

Comment: Start by drawing a figure. You must find the intersections of the two circles

Comment: @Andrei Found it at (3.5,3.5) , (0.0) what to do next?

Comment: @Andrei Can't proceed thereafter. Please help

Comment: @David Hello, Please look at the two answers provided. That ought to do it for you

Comment: @imranfat Integrator's solve is what i needed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**HINT**

Take a look to the graph

[image]

and use that for a quarter

- $A_{circle}=\frac{\pi R^2}4$
- $A_{triangle}=\frac12R^2$

Comment: Thanks you but integrator provided me what i wanted

Comment: @David Did you get how to use the given hint? we do not need integral to calculate the area between the circles.

Comment: @please help me dealing with two different answers

Comment: @David Note that the area between the circles is $2(A_{circle}-A_{triangle})$

Comment: It is coming around 7

Comment: while integrator said 12

Comment: @David I didn't check the integral but if you count the square in the graph you'll see that 7 is more likely to be true.

Comment: but that is contradictory . That was exactly the conflict , so I asked the question

Comment: @David ok I'll check the integral

Comment: Thanks for helping. Please inform me why such variable values are coming. For the moment I am not voting for any correct answer

Comment: @David I've found the error in the integral, that's the correct set up http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int++(3.5%5E2-(x-3.5)%5E2)%5E.5-(-(3.5%5E2-x%5E2)%5E.5%2B3.5)+dx+x%3D0..3.5

Comment: Indeed for the second circle the function to be considered is $$x^2 + (y- 3.5)^2 = (3.5)^2\implies  (y- 3.5)^2 = (3.5)^2-x^2 \implies (y- 3.5) =-\sqrt{ (3.5)^2-x^2} \implies y=3.5-\sqrt{ (3.5)^2-x^2} $$

Comment: yes, if one takes $y =\sqrt{(3.5)^2-x^2} $ as I did it leads to the incorrect answer.

Comment: @TheIntegrator Yes indeed we need to take the lower part of the circle that is $$(y- 3.5) =-\sqrt{ (3.5)^2-x^2} $$

Comment: @gimusi accepted your answer

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes graphing helps a lot. You can easily verify that the circles meet at the Origin and at $(3.5,3.5)$. You can also (with or without calculus) verify that at both points of intersection, the circles met at a right angle (Orthogonal intersection); that is, their respective tangents meet at a right angle. Now when you connect the points of intersection with a line segment, you "split up" the region they share into two equal regions. Now with some formulas of circle segment and circle sector, this is no longer a challenge

Comment: It would be great if you show me the equation or steps

Comment: I got stucked taking limits from 0 to (7/2) and substracting

Comment: These formulas are provided by Gimusi. Essentially, you find the are of the circle sector (which is a quarter of the whole circle) and you subtract from it the area of the right triangle (base and height is the radius of the circle). Then double up.

Comment: I already noted that one

Comment: @imranafat help me look at integrator comment section

Answer (score 3):

You need to find the points where they intersect, since you already fund that to be $(0,0)$ and $(3.5,3.5)$ I'll skip that step;

next  to find the area you find the definite integral ;

$A = \displaystyle\int_0^{3.5}\bigg(\sqrt{(3.5)^2-(x-3.5)^2}+\sqrt{(3.5)^2-x^2}-3.5\bigg)\,dx$

Comment: @Integrator But that doesn't help sir. I did the same. I got around 12.

Comment: Ok accepting your answer

Comment: @TheIntegrator It was the numerical value the OP was looking for, nothing else.

Comment: @imranfat,i didnt realise that , sorry.

Comment: @David Id rather you just vote my answer but accept gimusi's answer as it better imo

Comment: @The integrator ok accepting his one

Comment: @TheIntegrator Thanks! but let the OP is free to select the answer he/she prefer!

Comment: @integrator Gimusi answer is coming around 7

Comment: @integrator via integration it is coming 12

Comment: why so?? please help

Comment: @David no 7 is gimusi had the correct answer, ill delete this post. I got 12 because of the fact that since a circle isnt a function when you take the integral it takes the whole value from the top of the circle. You can fix that by adding a negative sign.

Comment: @The Integrator Then show the fix in your answer please

Comment: @David i edited before i posted the comment

Comment: @The Integrator I feel relaxed now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple geometry, like in the answers provided by other people. If you must use integrals, @gimusi provided a figure for you. Integrate $y_U(x)-y_L(x)$ for $x$ between $0$ and $3.5$. $y_U$ is the equation of the upper curve, $y_l$ is the equation of the lower curve.

Comment: Integrator gave the answer

Comment: help me look at integrator comment section